# Taking value from one dataframe and passing that value into loop of SqlContext

Tags: apache-spark

Looking to try do something like this:

I have a dataframe that is one column of ID's called ID_LIST. With that column of id's I would like to pass it into a Spark SQL call looping through ID_LIST using foreach returning the result to another dataframe.

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
val id_list = sqlContext.sql("select distinct id from item_orc")
id_list.registerTempTable("ID_LIST")
id_list.foreach(i => println(i)
```

id_list println output:

```
[123]
[234]
[345]
[456]
```

Trying to now loop through ID_LIST and run a Spark SQL call for each:

```
id_list.foreach(i => { 
    val items = sqlContext.sql("select * from another_items_orc where id = " + i
    items.foreach(println)
}
```

First.. not sure how to pull the individual value out, getting this error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot recognize input near '[' '123' ']' in expression specification; line 1 pos 61
```

Second: how can I alter my code to output the result to a dataframe I can use later ?

Thanks, any help is appreciated!

Comment: what is the datatype of id column in item_orc ?

Comment: could you add the missing closing braces to your code?

Answer (score 1):

**Answer To First Question**

When you perform the "foreach" Spark converts the dataframe into an RDD of type [Row](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Row). Then when you println on the RDD it prints the Row, the first row being "[123]". It is boxing [] the elements in the row. The elements in the row are accessed by position. If you wanted to print just 123, 234, etc... try

```
id_list.foreach(i => println(i(0)))
```

Or you can use native primitive access

```
id_list.foreach(i => println(i.getString(0))) //For Strings
```

Seriously... Read the documentation I have linked about Row in Spark. This will transform your code to:

```
id_list.foreach(i => {
  val items = sqlContext.sql("select * from another_items_orc where id = " + i.getString(0))
  items.foreach(i => println(i.getString(0)))
})
```

**Answer to Second Question**

I have a sneaking suspicion about what you actually are trying to do but I'll answer your question as I have interpreted it.

Let's create an empty dataframe which we will union everything to it in a loop of the distinct items from the first dataframe.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StringType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

// Create the empty dataframe. The schema should reflect the columns
// of the dataframe that you will be adding to it.
val schema = new StructType()
  .add("col1", StringType, true)

var df = ss.createDataFrame(ss.sparkContext.emptyRDD[Row], schema)

// Loop over, select, and union to the empty df 
id_list.foreach{ i =>
  val items = sqlContext.sql("select * from another_items_orc where id = " + i.getString(0))
  df = df.union(items)
}
df.show()
```

You now have the dataframe `df` that you can use later.

NOTE: An easier thing to do would probably be to join the two dataframes on the matching columns.

```
import sqlContext.implicits.StringToColumn
val bar = id_list.join(another_items_orc, $"distinct_id" === $"id", "inner").select("id")
bar.show()
```

Comment: Thanks , this is very helpful.